# Venera 13/14 Design specifications

Tags: history, soviet-union, reference-request, venera

Does anyone know where I could find design specifications, plan sets, or other documentation for the Venera 13 or Venera 14 spacecraft?  These are Soviet spacecrafts from the 1980s.

I suppose if anything exists publicly it would be in Russian, but even that would be helpful.

Comment: In English ask to https://mobile.twitter.com/DonaldM38768041